# Monomorphisms Between Infinite Graphs

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism, monomorphisms, infinite-graphs

I'm really curious about this question:

> Let $G(V_G,E_G)$ and $H(V_H,E_H)$ be infinite (infinite!, not finite) graphs, such that $$|V_G|=|V_H|,$$ and let $f$, $g$ be functions $f: G\rightarrow H$, $g: H\rightarrow G$ such that $$\text{$f$ and $g$ are monomorphisms}.$$
>
> By the given information, is it true to say that $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic?

From the given information, $G$ is isomorphic to a subgraph of $H$, and $H$ is isomorphic to a subgraph of $G$.  If $f$ or $g$ is not an isomorphism, then $G$ is a proper subgraph of itself and $H$ is a proper subgraph of itself.  This doesn't seem to create a contradiction.

Comment: I think it's related to Schroder- Berstein theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem

Comment: I thought so, but it seems that it depends about more things.

Comment: Vertices of G and 
Vertices of H

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  For instance, let $G$ be a complete graph on an infinite set and let $H$ be a disjoint union of $G$ and one more vertex.  Then there is an obvious monomorphism $G\to H$, and there is also a monomorphism $H\to G$ (just take any injection on vertices, and it is automatically a homomorphism since $G$ is complete).  However, $G$ and $H$ are not isomorphic.

Comment: A homomorphism of graph? How do you define this

Comment: A homorphism preserves adjacency. So if $u-v$ is an edge in $G$, and $f: G\rightarrow H$ is a homomorphism, then $f(u)-f(v)$ is an edge in $H$. Monomorphisms will just be a special kind of homomorphism.